# Unable to read trace definition file Microsoft Analysis Services TraceDefinition 12.0.5553 when running SQL Server profiler

Tags: sql-server, ssas, sql-server-2014, sql-server-profiler

I'm getting below error when I want to start a trace in profiler

> Unable to read trace definition file Microsoft Analysis Services TraceDefinition 12.0.5553.xml. Click OK to retrieve it from server. Retrieval may take a few moments

I tried many advise can be found over the web. no luck so far.

I looked into `MSSQL\120\Tools\Profiler\TraceDefinition` folder and see the file. there are bunch of the same xml with different version there. So I delete the 5553 file and the ran profiler. I was able to start a trace and the next time I opened profiler, I got the same error.

I looked into the folder and I saw the evil file is there again. Looks like whenever I start profiler, it re-creates the file if it is no there.

Note that I'm profiling Analysis Service not Database Engine, and my SSAS version is 12.0.5553, the same as the xml file.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same issue a few weeks ago. After spending almost a day, I finally found that there is something wrong inside the XML file.

You can resolve the issue by editing the content of XML. Open the XML and find the `<BUILDNUMBER>` node. if it is something other than **`5553`**, change it to **`5553`**.

Looks like the wrong build number on that node will cause the issue.

Comment: Thank you @FLICKER. You saved my day. This looks like a bug in MS!

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue, but in my case the xml file's version was missing.

*Preferred solution:* (Download xml file from a working server/ other system)
https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2016/05/14/sql-server-fix-sql-profiler-error-cannot-retrieve-trace-definition-sql-server-version/

Since the preferred solution didn't work for me, I had to download the file from :
http://fanclutch.com/PicsDocs/13579-2.cer?browse=C:%5CProgram%20Files%20(x86)%5CMicrosoft%20SQL%20Server%5C140%5CTools%5CProfiler%5CTraceDefinitions

**I don't recommend downloading files from unverified sources** (but I had already spent too much time on it), so I compared the file contents with the older version and the difference was only in 2 nodes. I copied the existing file and modified it:
[image: On left is file from that website and right file is my local]